# Updating JSON value in PostgreSQL 15

Tags: sql, json, database, postgresql

I need to update a specific value in a column with the json type.
All solutions I found online are either for jsonb or don't seem quite right and give me an syntax error and I don't know why.

That we are on the same page: it's a Postgres 15.3 database that was created like this:

```
create table if not exists "DOCF000T6"."assignments"
(
    id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    correlation_id VARCHAR ( 31 ) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    reference_id VARCHAR ( 100 ),
    jdata json NOT NULL,
    errormassage VARCHAR
);
```

And the one json that needs to be edited:

```
{
    "directoryRefId": "00DhDRC53dkoMUsC73znji4UoDUz",
    "useragent": "agent-ftps",
    "creationdate": "2023-12-12 15:41:03.3",
    "data": {
        "variables": {
            "dms-dokument-name": "Notifiation 22.09.2022.pdf",
            "dms-vo-remind": "false",
            "dms-messagebox": "E_BN",
            "dms-file-number": "0000-15840",
            "dms-pio-oe": "MUB",
        }
    }
}
```

I need to update the dms-file-number like this

```
UPDATE assignments
SET jdata['data']['variables']['dms-file-number']  = '0001-05840'
WHERE 
jdata-> 'data' -> 'variables' ->> 'dms-file-number' = '0000-15840';
```

I know that something like that should work for jsonb, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: You could open it up with `json_each()`, replace your value, then close it back up with `json_build _object()`. Nested value means you'll have to nest that too. Or, if you're not worried about reordering, stripping whitespace and deduplicating keys, you can just cast it to `jsonb`, use `jsonb_set()`, then cast it back to `json`.

Comment: 1) Your JSON example is not valid. Lose the `,` at the end of `"dms-pio-oe": "MUB",`. 2) This `jdata['data']['variables']['dms-file-number']` is not going to work with `jsonb`. 3) Per previous comment use `jsonb_set()` from here [JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Why 2)? [Looks fine to me.](https://dbfiddle.uk/bSvaQGFh) The only problem is that anything that puts it through a `json::jsonb` cast will move things around, deflate and dedupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you can cast to `::jsonb`, use [`jsonb_set()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#id-1.5.8.22.8.13.2.2.13.1.1.1), then cast back to `::json`. A side effect of that will be removed insignificant whitespace, reordered and deduplicated keys. You can restore formatting by running the value through `jsonb_pretty()` on its way back: [demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1JU7xdKf)

```sql
update "DOCF000T6"."assignments" 
set jdata=jsonb_pretty(
            jsonb_set(
              jdata::jsonb,
              '{data,variables,dms-file-number}',
              '"0777-7"' ) )::json
where (jdata#>>'{data,variables,dms-file-number}') = '0000-15840'
returning *;
```

Some display configurations might line-wrap `jsonb_pretty()`fied `jdata` in the table below. The [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1JU7xdKf) should preserve the real resulting format.

| id | correlation_id | referece_id | jdata | errormassage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | correlation_id1 | *null* | { "data": { "variables": { "dms-pio-oe": "MUB", "dms-vo-remind": "false", "dms-messagebox": "E_BN", "dms-file-number": "0777-7", "dms-dokument-name": "Notifiation 22.09.2022.pdf" } }, "useragent": "agent-ftps", "creationdate": "2023-12-12 15:41:03.3", "directoryRefId": "00DhDRC53dkoMUsC73znji4UoDUz" } | *null* |

You could also consider if it's maybe worth to `alter` the column permanently and leave it as `jsonb`, which will make it lighter, faster and conveniently indexable, adding lots of flexibility through support of additional operators and functions, at the expense of having to cascade this change to where the value's used in your code. Also some minor behavioral changes, like inability to hold duplicate keys, preserve custom formatting and custom key order.

```sql
alter table "DOCF000T6"."assignments" alter column jdata type jsonb;
update "DOCF000T6"."assignments" 
  set jdata['data']['variables']['dms-file-number']='"0999-9"'
where jdata['data']['variables']['dms-file-number']='"0000-15840"';
```

---

If formatting and whitespace were your primary concern, you'll be disappointed with the solution using pure `json` without `jsonb`: it can preserve custom key order and duplicate keys but exploding, then re-aggregating the object still wipes the whitespace. Here I added a `replace()` to add some newlines for readability:

```sql
update "DOCF000T6"."assignments" 
set jdata=(
select replace(json_object_agg(
         k1,
         case when k1<>'data' then v1 
              else json_build_object(
                     'variables',
                     (select json_object_agg(
                               k2,
                               case when k2<>'dms-file-number' then v2 
                                    else '"0777-7"' 
                               end
                               order by n2)
                       from json_each(v1->'variables')
                              with ordinality as variables(k2,v2,n2) ))
          end
          order by n1)::text, '",', E'",\n')::json
from json_each(jdata)with ordinality as top_level_dict(k1,v1,n1)
)
where (jdata#>>'{data,variables,dms-file-number}') = '0000-15840'
returning *;
```

| id | correlation_id | referece_id | jdata | errormassage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | correlation_id1 | *null* | { "directoryRefId" : "00DhDRC53dkoMUsC73znji4UoDUz", "useragent" : "agent-ftps", "creationdate" : "2023-12-12 15:41:03.3", "data" : {"variables" : { "dms-dokument-name" : "Notifiation 22.09.2022.pdf", "dms-vo-remind" : "false", "dms-messagebox" : "E_BN", "dms-file-number" : "0777-7", "dms-pio-oe" : "MUB" }} } | *null* |

As you can see, it's not pretty and as you can guess, it's pretty slow compared to `jsonb`. To make things worse, you should actually add a middle level to make sure you don't lose additional entries neighbouring `variables` under `data` - this now assumes there will only ever be `variables` as the only key under `data` and if there's anything else, this would discard that.

Comment: Thanks a lot your first statement was all i needed. i just trew out the jsonb_pretty because i realy don't need it in my case and i added a WHERE to not completely wipe my Database.

Comment: @YannikKamper Good point. I updated the answer to add that to all examples and the demo

Answer (score 0):

Zegarek'S anser workex perfectly
i just trew out the jsonb_pretty because i realy don't need it in my case and i added a WHERE to not completely wipe my Database

```
update "DOCF000T6"."assignments" 
set jdata=jsonb_set(
              jdata::jsonb,
              '{data,variables,dms-file-number}',
              '"0001-05840"' )::json
WHERE 
correlation_id='00DgLDdcUUXyLeIF9USLAf78fryu'
```